# Why is "new" operator working for detaching a eventhandler using -=?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Why do I have to use the following to detach an event?

```
object.myEvent -= new MyEvent(EventHandler);
```

I am some how irritated that the **new** operator is working.

Can some one explain?

**Update**

I already know that i don't have to use the new operator for detaching events, but it is still the auto complete suggestion in Visual Studio 2010. My real question is how does -= new work for the detach process. How can a new object / delegate match a prior created  object / delegate on the += side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to use the `new` operator. You haven't had to since C# 2.0 came out:

```
foo.SomeEvent += EventHandler;
foo.SomeEvent -= EventHandler;
```

This uses a *method group conversion* to create a delegate from the method group (the name of the method). This isn't just for events, either:

```
Action<string> writeToConsole = Console.WriteLine;
```

EDIT: As for *how* it works:

- Using `-=` on an event just ends up calling the "remove" accessor, which typically uses `-=` on a delegate... (at least effectively)
- Using `-=` on a delegate is syntactic sugar for [`Delegate.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove.aspx)
- `Delegate.Remove` uses delegate equality - two delegate instances are equal if they have the same method and the same target instance (for instance methods)

Note that using a method group conversion will still create a new instance of the delegate each time you go through the code.

Comment: Okay, "So now I'm irritated I have to use a += and then a -=, what gives?" ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you give me more details? I know i dont have to use new. But it is still the auto complete in Visual Studio 2010. (if you type foo.SomeEvent += Visual Studio suggest to do += new ... I would like to know how .net handles detaching internally. How can a new operator match a prior created object / delegate?

Comment: @Grrbrr404: Edited appropriately. You might want to consider retitling your question - if you know that you don't have to use the new operator for detaching an events, a question of "Why do I have to use “new” to detach an Event handler using -=?" seems pretty odd.

Comment: Intresting, thanks! :) And yes, i already updated my question to be more clear. I hope it is ok now.